# How to change opacity of text widget to 0.7 with flutter extension?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I need change style of Text Widget in flutter with an extension.
this extension must be  change opacity of Text Widget to 0.7 .
when i used in on Text widget , i can change opacity of widget to 0.7.

**UPDATE:**
if Text widget has style and color, this ok . but when not have style receive null error .

```
extension TextStyleOpacity on Text {
  Text  opacity70(){
    return Text("A", style:this.style!.copyWith(color:this.style?.color!.withOpacity(0.3) ) ,) ;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code you've already tried?

Comment: `Text` and `Opacity` widgets are stateless.  If you need to change the opacity, you will need to rebuild your widget tree with a new value.  I don't think this makes any sense as an extension method.  Why must it be an extension method?

Comment: Did I understood correctly that: Initially opacity is 100%, but when u tap on any button, it triggers opacity of a text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. I change this extension for text style and solved , answer is  :

```
    extension TextStyleOpacity on TextStyle?{
  TextStyle colorOpacity ({required BuildContext context}){
    Color? color =this==null?DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.color: this?.color;
    if(this==null){
      return DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.copyWith(color: color!.withOpacity(0.7));
    }else{
      return this!.copyWith(color: color!.withOpacity(0.7));
    }
  }
}
```

And is used like this example:

```
Text(textWidget.data! ,style:textWidget.style.colorOpacity(context: context),);
```